# Rename Filter Label Model Admin Django

Tags: django, django-filter, django-modeladmin

Is it possible to change this label in the list filter from model admin without creating a custom filter?
[image]

I'm using the same external model for 2 different fields and user needs to filter the table using both fields  (separately or combining them).

Without the rename, the Admin view will have 2 filters with same name applying to different fields.(see picture)
Not the best ux.

[image]

The first column is a field not in this model it is calling related model field as a list_display and listFilter:

```
list_display = ([...] 'contract_gjl_entity', 'gjl_paying_entity', [...])
list_filter = (
    [...]
    ('gjl_paying_entity__name', DropdownFilter),
    ('contract__gjl_entity__name', DropdownFilter),
    [...]


# Function that get the entities using contract id field and join them in a csv text to show in grid

def contract_gjl_entity(obj):
        contract_id = obj.contract_number
        contract = Contract.objects.get(id=contract_id)
        return ", ".join(str(seg) for seg in contract.gjl_entity.all())
```

What I need is to rename the 'By GJL Entity' --> 'By Contract Entity' and the other 'By GJL Entity' --> 'By Paying Entity'

Comment: can you update your `modelForm` too?

Comment: I've only used modelForm to edit the values or fields being shown there. ¿can I change the filter name there?

Comment: yes, you can change,using `labels`. for example : `labels={'any_field_name':'your_custom_label_name'}` in `Meta` class inside Modelform.

Comment: see my updated comment.

Comment: Not sure if this is what I need.. I've updated the Question adding more details of how this is build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin

def custom_titled_filter(title):
    class Wrapper(admin.FieldListFilter):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = admin.FieldListFilter.create(*args, **kwargs)
            instance.title = title
            return instance
    return Wrapper


After that in your ModelAdmin class:

list_filter = (
    ('fieldname', custom_titled_filter('My Custom Title')),
    'plain_field',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).